# Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target - Angular

Tags: angular

```
    {
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

**The code inside the web.service.ts file is  :-**

```
 async getData(daOne){
   try {
  daOne=(daOne) ? '/' + daOne: '';
  var response = await this.http.get(this.HOME_URL+'/MyPage'+daOne).toPromise();
  this.news = response.json();

}
```

**The code inside my component :-**

```
  ngOnInit() {
  var data=this.route.snapshot.params.name;
  this.webService.getData(data);
  }
```

Well Here is my code when i have tried to perform this operation then it shows me the error which i have specify inside my title... i have search in google but unable to solve this error... so please anyone help me to solve this error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are this is actually an issue with a function call from the template not matching the parameter list of the function it is trying to call in the TypeScript of the component.  Check your template for method calls and verify the parameters are correct.

For example:

Template:
`<button onClick="clickHandler()">Click this!</button>`

Typescript: `clickHandler(event) { ... }`